# how to concate list of strings by element

Tags: kdb

I have two lists for example:

```
x:("AA","BB","CC")
y:("1","2","3")
```

I would like to target the concatenation of both lists element wise as below:

```
z = ("AA1","BB2","CC3")
```

I have tried the following which only works if the lists have one string:

```
(x,y)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [eachboth adverb](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-both) which takes one element from each list at a time and perform operation.

Also change comma to semicolon in your x and y list  to get list with 3 items.

```
 q) x:("AA";"BB";"CC")
 q) y:("1";"2";"3")
 q) x,'y
```

Output:

("AA1";"BB2";"CC3")